# Python: how read csv data if column having data in the format of key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new to python.
I need to read csv file which has various columns.
In csv file One column contains data like key and value pairs.
Using pandas how to extract the keys and values of that column from csv.

Ex: column name : `fruit`

Data in that column :

```
{ ""apple": "1,2,3,4", "orange":"5,6,7,8"}
```

How to get keys and its values of fruit column from csv file?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Refer to [MCVE] for more guidance.

Comment: Give us a proper csv example and proper output format.

Comment: FruitsData.csv has two columns("id" and "fruit" and two rows. Example of csv data is shown below.
Id.  fruit
1.   {"apple":"1,2,3,4", "orange":"5,6,7,8}

2.    {"apple": "11,12,13,14", "grapes": "15,16,17, 18"}

I need to read keys and its values in each row. 
Expected output:
Print "apple", "orange" value of 1st row. And "apple", "grapes" value of second row.

Answer (score 0):

To read the .csv, I use pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
fruit_df = pd.read('directory_where_csv_is_saved/file_name.csv')
```

I would widen the dataframe to hold more columns by unpacking the dictionary column "Fruit" by first getting the keys from the dictionaries within the 'Fruit' column and converting that set of keys to an iterable list.

```
key_set = set()
for i in range(len(fruit_df)):
    for key in fruit_df['Fruit'][i].keys():
        if key not in key_set:
            key_set.add(key)
        else:
            pass
key_set_list = list(key_set)
```

Then unpack the dictionary:

```
for i in range(len(key_set_list)):
    fruit_df[key_set_list[i]] = [d.get(key_set_list[i]) for d in fruit_df['Fruit']]
```

Your dataframe should be wider (more columns) with each new column being the dictionary key, and the respective values in the applicable rows.